Implementing basic kMeans algorithm
I try to implement the following basic k-Means algorithm in R (from James et al (2023).An Introduction to Statistical Learning, p. 517):

The code I came up with is working and produces a reasonable result (every 100 obs build 1 cluster, which corresponds with the data generating process).
The code currently looks like this:
# predefined number of clusters
k <- 3
   
# data simulation
set.seed(1234)
X <- matrix(rnorm(30000),nrow=300,ncol=100)    # 300 obs with 100 features each
X[101:200,] <- X[101:200,] + 1
X[201:300,] <- X[201:300,] + 2

# random classification for each obs
class <- matrix(sample(1:k,dim(X)[1],replace=TRUE,set.seed(123)),nrow=dim(X)[1])

# Running k-Means Algorithm
kmeans.basic <- function(X,class,k) {
  
  # total obs
  points <- dim(X)[1]
  
  # classification
  classification <- class
  
  # number of modified class assigments per iteration
  mod.assignments <- NA
  
  repeat{
  
    # finding cluster centroids (rows = cluster, cols = feature mean)
    center <- aggregate(X,list(class),mean)
    rownames(center) <- 1:3
    center <- center[,-1]

    # calculating euclidean distance for each point
    
    EuclideanDist <- matrix(nrow=300,ncol=3)
    
    for (point in 1:points) {
      for (cl in 1:k) {
        EuclideanDist[point,cl] <- sqrt(sum((X[point,] - center[cl,])^2))
      }
    }
    
    # new classification
    class.new <- apply(EuclideanDist,1,which.min)
    
    # classification per iteration
    classification <- cbind(classification,unname(class.new))
    
    # modified assignments per iteration
    mod.assignments <- c(mod.assignments,unname(points-table(class.new==class)["TRUE"]))
    
    # stop if assignments don't change anymore
    if(identical(class.new,class)) break
    
    # new classification for next iteration
    class <- class.new
  
  }
  
  return(list("modified_assignements" = mod.assignments,"classifications"=classification))
  
}

kmeans.basic(X,class,k)

My question is whether the for-loop can be replaced with a quicker code. So I want to change this loop...
EuclideanDist <- matrix(nrow=300,ncol=3)

for (point in 1:points) {
  for (cl in 1:k) {
    EuclideanDist[point,cl] <- sqrt(sum((X[point,] - center[cl,])^2))
  }
}

...into something like this:
index <- expand.grid(lapply(c(points,k),seq_len))
EuclideanDist <- array(dist(rbind(X[index$Var1,],center[index$Var2,])),dim=c(points,k))

But the results of the array EuclideanDist in the first iteration are already not the same:
for-loop results (for first 10 obs; col 1 = Eucl.Dist to cluster centroid 1,...):
EuclideanDist
            [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
  [1,] 15.054331 13.498277 12.891710
  [2,] 14.676493 12.986101 12.458025
  [3,] 14.604512 12.786467 12.161778
  [4,] 15.795601 13.977206 13.645632
  [5,] 16.475889 14.753928 14.011286
  [6,] 14.506822 12.897481 12.381961
  [7,] 17.822123 15.913398 15.451605
  [8,] 15.569600 13.918099 13.397844
  [9,] 14.593612 12.841399 12.340844
 [10,] 16.350167 14.664481 14.148517

results with expand.grid():
EuclideanDist
           [,1]     [,2]     [,3]
  [1,] 13.08934 13.08934 13.08934
  [2,] 13.27003 13.27003 13.27003
  [3,] 12.65392 12.65392 12.65392
  [4,] 14.29587 14.29587 14.29587
  [5,] 14.66200 14.66200 14.66200
  [6,] 14.41147 14.41147 14.41147
  [7,] 13.45788 13.45788 13.45788
  [8,] 13.33575 13.33575 13.33575
  [9,] 14.77679 14.77679 14.77679
 [10,] 12.77164 12.77164 12.77164

Can anybody please help with the alternative code using expand.grid() to replace the for-loop? Why isn't this working? Thank you!
